# Adding events to with google calendar api using php

Tags: php, api, calendar

I'm trying to add an event to my calendar using the code below but I keep getting errors about needing to refresh the token. I wasted a lot of time this morning using the wrong version of the api and having problems with autoload but I seem to be getting closer to a working code. I don't code in php much so please forgive any stupid mistakes.

> Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Error
>   refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{   "error" : "invalid_grant"

The code I'm using is:

```
<?php

function calendarize ($title, $desc, $ev_date, $cal_id) {

    session_start();

    /************************************************
    Make an API request authenticated with a service
    account.
    ************************************************/
    set_include_path( '../google-api-php-client/src/');

    require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
    require_once 'Google/Client.php';
    require_once 'Google/Service/Calendar.php';

    //obviously, insert your own credentials from the service account in the Google Developer's console
    $client_id = 'xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';
    $service_account_name = 'xxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
    $key_file_location = '../google-api-php-client/xxxx4.p12';

    if (!strlen($service_account_name) || !strlen($key_file_location))
        echo missingServiceAccountDetailsWarning();

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("dsaccalendar");

    if (isset($_SESSION['service_token'])) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['service_token']);
    }

    $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
    $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $service_account_name, 
        array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'), 
        $key
    );
    $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
    if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
    }
    $_SESSION['service_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

    $calendarService = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
    $calendarList = $calendarService->calendarList;

    //Set the Event data
    $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
    $event->setTimeZone('Europe/London');
    $event->setSummary($title);
    $event->setDescription($desc);

    $start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
    $start->setDateTime($ev_date);
    $event->setStart($start);

    $end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
    $end->setDateTime($ev_date);
    $event->setEnd($end);

    $createdEvent = $calendarService->events->insert($cal_id, $event);

    echo $createdEvent->getId();



} 

calendarize('Test Event2','some stuff 2about the test event','2016-01-01T19:15:00','xxxx@xxx.co.uk');





?>
```